# Incorrect detecting namespaces in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a simple model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Order::Product'
    has_many :attributes, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Order::Attribute'
    belongs_to :customer
    has_one :invoice_address, class_name: 'Order::Address'
    has_one :delivery_address, class_name: 'Order::Address'

    validates :number, presence: true
    validates :total_amount, presence: true
end
```

I wanted to add products and attributes to orders. I created 2 new files
models/order/product.rb

```
class Order::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

and models/order/attribute.rb

```
class Order::Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

I created seeds file with code:

```
dev_customer = Customer.create(:name => 'dev')

first_order = dev_customer.orders.create(:total_amount => 555, :paid_amount => 555)

first_order.products.create(:name => 'First product', :price => 111, :qty => 1)
first_order.products.create(:name => 'Second product', :price => 222, :qty => 2)
but when I execute rake db:setup I receive error
```

> You cannot call create unless the parent is saved

on line 5. What do I do wrong?

On rspec tests I receive a different error

```
$ rspec
/home/bartek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:464:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Product, expected /home/bartek/rails_apps/allemag/app/models/order/product.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Here is my config/application.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Allemag
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
  end
end
```

What do I do wrong? I think that rails has problems with namespaces, but have no idea how to fix it. I'm using rails4.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the autoload path from the configuration? Rails should be able to infer the model filename from class name. Make sure you are always using the namespaced version--'Product' should not appear on its own.

Comment: I tested your solution but I receive error `uninitialized constant Order::Order::Attribute` in rspec tests

Comment: Might help if you showed the test code.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting the error loading your models in rspec because the module "Order" isn't properly defined.  You can change the declaration of the Order class as follows to fix your class loading issue:

```
module Order
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
  end
end
```

When you define a class name with a module included, this *USES* the module, but does not define the module if it doesn't exist.  Explicitly declaring the module and then declaring the class within will define the module and add the Class within that namespace.

Comment: I receive error `/app/models/order/product.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Order is not a module (TypeError)` so it did not solved my problem